# using CURL in php to retrieve data from an api

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I have an api link which is working fine on terminal. I wand to use same api link to retrieve data using CURL in php. I tried below code:

```php
<?php

// set up the curl resource

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'urlxxxxx');
// execute the request

$output = curl_exec($ch);

// output the profile information - includes the header

echo  "curl response is : <br> ".($output). PHP_EOL;

// close curl resource to free up system resources

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

but I am getting response as :

> curl response is :
>   { "error" : "JSON syntax error: malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before \"(end of string)\") at /usr/share/perl5/JSON.pm line 171.\n" }

I am new to CURL guide me regarding the issue for resolving it.

Comment: You have no `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option to send the parameters.

Comment: I don't want to send any parameters i just wanted to retrieve data.

Comment: The API expects parameters in JSON format. Maybe you need to send an empty array or object.

Comment: If i remove the line curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); i get Error 404

Comment: Can you show the command line version that works fine?

Comment: That `-d` option is the equivalent of `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{}");
```

so you send an empty JSON object as the parameter. This is the PHP equivalent of

```
-d "{}"
```

from the command line.

To put some other array into the post data, use `json_encode`.

```
$data = array('userId' => array(), 
              'user_list' => array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8")
             );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data);
```

Comment: How can I add this input format  "array [ {\n\tinteger: userID;\n} ] user_list\n"  , as CURL_POSTFIELDS ?

Comment: Use `json_encode` to convert a PHP array to JSON. See the updated answer.

Comment: can you provide an example. ?

Comment: curl -v  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://184.73.165.170:3000/api/3ace632b194e4366b821f7775b51cc4e/get-user-info -d "{\"userID\":[],\"user_list\":[ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8" ]}"   now how to set curl post fiellds????

Comment: Just create a PHP array that contains the data you want, and call `json_encode()`. I've updated the answer to match that data.

Comment: curl -v  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://184.73.165.170:3000/api/3ace632b194e4366b821f7775b51cc4e/get-sensor-transit -d "{ \"sensorID\" : \"1234\" , \"objectID\":\"2\" , \"begin\":\"2015-07-01\",\"end\":\"2015-07-23\"  }"                                      works on terminal but when i include same in curl_setopt($ch,CURL_POSTFIELDS,"{\"sensorID\":\"1234\",\"objectID\":\"1\" , \"begin\":\"2015-07-01\",\"end\":\"2015-07-23\"}");                       it gives json error

Comment: Don't try to create JSON by hand. Use `json_encode`. And for simplicity, put single quotes around your strings so you don't have to escape all the double quotes.

Comment: I have php file which consist of curl code so as to access an api. But when I upload this file on server and try to execute it via url no output is shown. Also file symbol is not shown as it is shown for php file in parent directory of server. Guide me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Do other PHP files run on the server?

Comment: yes other php files run on server. Only php file which consist of curl code so as to access an api does not work on server.

Comment: Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of the script. Do you get any warnings?

Comment: It has to be after `<?php` like any other PHP function call, of course.

Comment: Didn't you just post a new question for this problem? Why are you still commenting here?

Comment: I was not allowed to post question so for the time I commented question here. Nowwhen I am aloowed I posted the question. If you have any futher solution please ans me on my posted question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645397/php-file-with-curl-commands-not-working-on-server?noredirect=1#comment51237761_31645397

Answer (score 0):

You either need to set the method to 'GET'  by removing `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);`
Or supplying valid JSON  `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{}");`