# php file with CURL commands not working on Server

Tags: php, curl, server, execution

I have php file which consist of curl code so as to access an api. But when I upload this file on server and try to execute it via url no output is shown. Also file symbol is not shown as it is shown for php file. Guide me how to solve this problem. The code in php file is :

```html
 <?php   // set up the curl resource

    $ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"{}"); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://184.73.165.170:3000/api/3ace632b194e4366b821f7775b51cc4e/get-ibeacon-contents'); // execute the request

    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // output the profile information - includes the header

    //echo "curl response is :".($output). PHP_EOL; print($output);

    // close curl resource to free up system resources

    curl_close($ch); ?>
```

[image]

My server index shows as shown in image. As per my understanding a php file symbol is different than what it is shown in image I uploaded. Can anyone suggest about this ,if it helps me resolve my aim.

Comment: After curl_exec, check for curl_error

Comment: `POSTFIELDS` should be url encoded string or array and I cant see any `<?php` sign in your code.

Comment: I added curl_exec still file is not executing.

Comment: @NeelIon please explain POSTFIELDS should be url encoded string or array ? n i bymistakenly forgot to add <?php in above question code while posting. I have it in the php file.

Comment: you can send post parameters using this format `key1=value1&key2=value2`.

Comment: but I have -d "{}" option while executing the url through terminal so I have used the same for POSTFIELDS

Comment: add this code before curl_close()
`var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
echo curl_errno($ch) . '-' . curl_error($ch);`
This will output errors

Comment: if I use CURL_URL link without port it gives no permission error.

Comment: Did you try my updated answer?

Comment: yes I tried same the url to php file just keeps loading

Comment: refer my uploaded image in question and also explaination any query please read again.

Comment: hi, did u found solution for this

Answer (score 0):

I tried on local and the cURL seems to work. If its working on local only and not on server then these are the things you should check:

- Enable cURL on server `;extension=php_curl.dll` and remove the semicolon`;` (uncomments) usually inside file `php/php.ini`
- If you are working locally on Windows and trying to upload to a Linux server, then you might want to change EOL for UNIX/OSX Format. You can do this using Notepad++ by going to `Edit -> EOL Conversion -> UNIX/OSX Format` and then upload.

Comment: CURL is enabled on server . we tried curl example files they are working fine. But only above file is not working.

Comment: refer my uploaded image in question and also explaination any query please read again.

Answer (score 0):

Try using your code this way

```
     <?php

        $json=json_encode(array('key1'=>'val1','key2'=>'val2'));

        $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://184.73.165.170:3000/api/3ace632b194e4366b821f7775b51cc4e/get-ibeacon-contents');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$json); 


        $output = curl_exec($ch);

        var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
        echo curl_errno($ch) . '-' . curl_error($ch);

        curl_close($ch); 

    ?>
```

Comment: refer my uploaded image in question and also explaination any query please read again.